# Exceptions handling

Tags: java, loops, exception

[image]

I want it allow the user to enter in two int after the incorrect input. I tried continue; in the catch block, but it only threw run-time errors. I just want it to go back to the top of the main method after the throwing the error. See how in the pic it didn't allow the user to input any numbers. I want to fix that part.

Here's the code. This is only for practice.

```
/**
practing exceptions, example 1 in book for exceptions 
*/ 

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class PracticeExceptions extends Exception {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     String response = "y";
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

     do{ 
     int n1, n2;
     double r;
     System.out.println("Please enter two numbers");

     try{
            n1 = keyboard.nextInt();
            n2 = keyboard.nextInt();
            r = (double) n1/n2;     

        System.out.format("Your answer: %.2f %n", r);

       }catch(Exception a){

       System.out.println("Invaild input please try again");

       }

       System.out.println("Again (y/n)");
       response = keyboard.next();

       }while(response.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
     }
   }
```

Comment: Catching and ignoring any exception, is extremely bad practice. Just use an `if`

Comment: Not sure what you mean, this is just for practice for lower level java. Maybe not the best, but I've only learned a limited amount of java. So, it's only for practical use

Comment: @MonkeyMonster I mean instead of using try-catch, use `if`. You are expecting the user to give you a value which is not valid (n2=0). Try-catch should be used for exceptions that are not depend on the user. You can do the same thing with `if(n2==0){isValid=false;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the invalid input in you scanner buffer

```
 }catch(Exception a){
    System.out.println("Invalid input please try again");
    keyboard.next();
 }
```

The code will now drop down to `System.out.println("Again (y/n)");`

If you want to loop back to the top add a `continue` after `keyboard.next();`

Comment: If I do that, it still doesn't asks the user to input two more ints or even allows them to

Comment: Thank you I just added continue, worked smoothly. I saw what was happening.